# What is the name of this bamboo looking plant?

Tags: identification

I recently found this plant hiding behind a bush.

Could someone please identify it?

[image: Unknown Plant]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plant is called the Mass Cane or Dracaena Massangea also known as [Dracaena fragrans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_fragrans) .  See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=mass%20cane) for other answers which expand on this.

From my previous answer

> It is a very popular tropical plant from Africa. In the wild this
>   plant reaches 15 m (49 ft) but specimens grown indoors can be easily
>   kept at ceiling height (about 2 m or 6 to 8 ft).
>
> Your plant has a red waxy substance on the end of the cane due to how
>   it is grown. A typical production cycle for this plant is for it to be
>   grown outside in Central America, Costa Rica is a common origin. The
>   plant is allowed to grow to twenty or thirty feet and then chain sawed
>   into various lengths. The trunks are then shipped to Florida in
>   containers and potted up. Growers will pack three or four trunks of
>   varying lengths into one pot and a sealant is put on the end of each
>   trunk to prevent rot.