# What plant is this and how do I save it?

Tags: identification, plant-care, propagation, cuttings

I've recently found this plant, which was already dying, maybe due to low temperatures, too much or too less water, poor soil...

[image]

Firstly, I'd like to know its name, in order to learn how to take care of it and how to reproduce it. My idea is, if possible, cut the upper part, which is still green, and make it grow apart. Lower leafs are almost dead, and they're not going to live anymore. Would this work? Should I put it first in water and maybe use some hormones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the name of this bamboo looking plant?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/what-is-the-name-of-this-bamboo-looking-plant)

Comment: @kevinsky no; that one only covers id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plant is called the Mass Cane or Dracaena Massangea also known as Dracaena fragrans . See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=massangea) for other answers which expand on this.

This plant propagates readily when rooted in water or even when a healthy stem is cut off and stuck in the pot.  Your plant is a bit stressed so rooting in water is the best way to go.

- Provide bright indirect light
- cut back from the top at least a foot or more
- put in water and change the water regularly

It should root within a month. Wait till the roots are at least two or three inches long and then pot up and grow on to a larger size.  The rest of the stem that is in the pot should bud out with new growth within a month or two.