# Plant Identification and Pet/Child Safety

Tags: identification

[image]

What type of plant is this?
Is it safe for children and pets?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What plant is this and how do I save it?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16146/what-plant-is-this-and-how-do-i-save-it)

Comment: Hi Kevinsky. The plant looks right, but as far as I can see, that question doesn't address the second part of this question, about safety for children and pets.

Answer (score 2):

This plant is called the Corn Plant; Dracaena fragrans 'Massangeana'...and yours looks horrible.  More light? Here is a good link for care.  Not poisonous...[Corn Plant and care](http://www.guide-to-houseplants.com/corn-plant.html).