# Can anyone identify this house plant - it has broad leaves and a rosette center? Dracena Family(?) but short trunk

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-recommendations

[image]Can anyone identify this house plant - it has broad leaves and a rosette center?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the name of this bamboo looking plant?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/what-is-the-name-of-this-bamboo-looking-plant)

Comment: This is a mass cane, or dracaena massangea.  Follow the link for an answer to a similar question

Comment: how about a picture from the side?

Comment: kevinsky. Appreciated input. New to forum. Checking on how to add profile image for identification purposes.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the plant from the side so we can see the stem?  Nice profile picture!

Comment: This Hanging basket was bought at a garden sale yesterday. A master Gardener id'd it as Scottish Pipe (also known as Dutchman's Pipe, I think) with English Ivy and Joy Sedum which may not be visible in photos. I agree with the Scottish Pipe (hence the stem projection on the right side on 2nd photo) and ivy but the main 3 main plants are not identified. I was originally lead to believe they were the Scottish plant but researching it I saw that the Scottish plant has heart shaped leaves - so what is this?

Comment: Not a mass cane then

Comment: @kevinsky To clarify, are you now thinking this is not a duplicate of the question you linked to?

Comment: @Sue that's right, more about information clarified it.  Not a duplicate

Comment: Welcome to the site, we're glad you found us! I agree with kevinsky, that's a nice profile picture! If you have trouble or questions about doing anything else on the site, just let us know.

Comment: Many Thanks to kevinsky and Sue for your kindness and assistance. I love this site....I just happened to have found it last week.... and look forward to participating. In the meantime. I'll continue my quest to ID this lovely plant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much research I have discovered that this is a [Callisia Fragrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callisia_fragrans) Plant (Synonymous: Spironema orthandrum or Spironema Fragrans)

Also known as a False Bromeliad, Chain Plant, Basket Plant, Family Doctor Plant. It is of the Commelinaceae Family. Considered a Subtropical with Holistic-Medicinal properties.

Acccording to *plantrescue.com*: Callisia fragrans is epidemic to Mexico and naturalized in the West Indies. Callisia fragrans is a long-lived creeping herbaceous plant with leaves crowded into rosette-like clusters and spreading laterally via long runners.

Callisia Fragrans grows fast and produces white or cream flowers from its tips. It prefers bright light including about three or four hours of direct sunlight each day.

Thanks to both kevinsky and Sue for their generous input.

Comment: I agree, a good match with the appearance. I added a link, You should mark this as the answer

Comment: Nice find! These things can be really hard to identify. I agree with @kevinsky that you should mark this as the right answer, so future readers will see that it's the best answer to the question. You do that by clicking on the checkmark under the number of votes on this answer. [This page](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) in our [help] explains the process. I'm so glad you like it here! You've already been a big help!

Comment: Appreciate the navigation tips Sue and kevinsky's help in the link....had not figured out how to do both yet......I'll keep watching and learn.